# DeafultcCellStyle format not working on unbound DataGridView C# Winforms

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an unbound DataGridView that I populate with data from an SQL database. One of the columns in the database is of type ‘datetime’.

On the load event of my winforms application, I use code below in order to format the column to only show date part of datetime column. However it shows the full datetime. I want 18/02/2020 and it’s showing 18/02/2020 00:00:00

```
dgv.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dgv.Columns["Date"].ValueType = typeof(System.DateTime);
```

How do I format the column to only show the date portion of the datetime column?

Comment: I have also added the code above to the DGV cell formatting event and it still does not apply the format.

Answer (score 1):

I added some data in the gridview within my code and tried your code above. The DefaultCellStyle.Format works well.

Which means that you might need to check the way you're retrieving the data from your SQL Database. You may be filling your grid with strings instead of "dates" for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is my code:

                // Retrieve the column information from the database.
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
                columnsValue = table.Columns;

Comment: This worked well for me :  

`SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = cnn;
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds, "sourceTable");

dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dgv.Columns["Date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";`